# Display byte array image onto Discord Rich Embed

Tags: c#, image, discord.net

My Discord bot can get a png image from my database and store it as a byte array. How would I embed this image onto Discord's Rich Embed using the c# Discord.Net library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that `SendFileAsync` has two constructors for a string file name and Stream respectively. A google search about Streams and byte arrays led me to [here](https://medium.com/@stevenscript/convert-a-byte-array-to-a-stream-in-c-840889a59174). Then I looked more into Discord.Net's EmbedBuilder Class and found information about [embedding a local image file in the rich embed](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.EmbedBuilder.html#usage-with-local-images)

Using those resources I wrote this and the image was displayed correctly

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream imgStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArrayImage))
{
       build.WithThumbnailUrl("attachment://anyImageName.png"); //or build.WithImageUrl("")
       await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(imgStream, "anyImageName.png", "", false, build.Build());
}
```